# HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED when updating weblogic version 12 to 14

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic, http2, network-protocols, http-1.1

An update was made to the infrastructure, going from weblogic 12 to version 14 with https.
After this, my application made in spring MVC presents several problems, including when loading images showing an error: HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR and when sending forms ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

I have changed the logic of some parts to send images to the server through fetch but the problems still occur.